# Contour integration with pole

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I wanted to integrate

$$\oint \frac{\sqrt{z+5}}{z^5}$$

around a circular contour radius $1$ center $0$.

So the function has pole at 0. How can I proceed from here?

Comment: use that $\sqrt{z+5}=\sqrt 5 \sqrt{z/5+1}$ and the binomial formula to find the coefficient of $z^4$ in the square root expansion as that gives you the residue you need

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cauchy's integral formula is

$$f^{(n)} (z_0) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}} dz$$
so
$$ \oint \frac{\sqrt{z+5}}{z^5} dz = \frac{2\pi i}{4!} \,\left.\frac{d^4}{dz^4}(z+5)^{1/2}\right|_{z=0}$$

$$ \oint \frac{\sqrt{z+5}}{z^5} dz = -\frac{2\pi i}{4!} \, \left. \frac{15}{16(5+z)^{7/2}}\right|_{z=0}$$

$$ \oint \frac{\sqrt{z+5}}{z^5} dz = -\frac{\pi i}{64\cdot 5^{5/2}} $$